# android.graphics.camera Error

Tags: android, graphics, camera

I am developing an Android app on eclipse and have been using android.graphics.camera to 3d transform images.  In a nutshell, my app takes a 2d image and gives it perspective.  My problem is that I also want to rotate the image around the screen while it is being transformed.

```
        final Matrix mMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();
        canvas.save();
        mCamera.save();
        mCamera.rotateX(60);
        mCamera.rotateY(0);
        mCamera.rotateZ(0); 
        mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
        mMatrix.preTranslate(-this.gridWidth / 2, -this.gridHeight);
        mMatrix.postTranslate(this.gridWidth / 2, this.gridHeight);
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        mCamera.restore();
        //Draw and move image here          
        canvas.restore();
```

When the image gets to the bottom of the screen, where the camera is translated, the image becomes distorted.  I see pieces of it on the screen but its like its being drawn backwards or sideways.  I've also tried rotating the image using the rotateZ property but the same effect occurs.  Once the image gets 'behind' the translation point, it just goes nuts.

I thought it might be an emulator bug so I loaded it on my Droid X and Acer Iconia and the effect remains the same.

I haven't seen anybody else have this problem so i figured someone here might have a clue as to what's going on.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be addressed with newer versions of Android that let you change the camera distance:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html#setLocation(float, float, float)

Comment: That option doesn't appear in the drop down menu for the camera.  Any idea why?